# AngularJS nvD3 Error - What versions are compatible?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I have the same problem as with this user: 
[Angular nvD3 Error: Invalid isolate scope definition for directive nvd3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270198/angular-nvd3-error-invalid-isolate-scope-definition-for-directive-nvd3)

The answer there said "use the latest angularjs" beyond Angular 1.1.4....but I am using the latest AngularJS!!  AngularJS v1.6.7

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: @georgeawg, it is almost the same code in the other thread - I have tried her code and got the same error; so the problem is environment related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with this setup

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/nvd3/build/nv.d3.css"/>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/d3@3/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/nvd3/build/nv.d3.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-nvd3/dist/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
```

[DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/kBPGjwyJM5gG6fFqkHtp?p=preview).

See [angular-nvd3 Issue  #539 - d3 version 4.x is not supported](https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/issues/539)

Comment: thanks, this worked despite the errors: angular.js:34191 Uncaught TypeError: window.angular.$$csp is not a function
    at angular.js:34191
angular.min.js:63 TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at Object.fn (app.js:182)
    at Object.$digest (angular.min.js:87)
    at Object.$apply (angular.min.js:89)
    at angular.min.js:16
    at Object.d [as invoke] (angular.min.js:28)
    at c (angular.min.js:16)
    at tb (angular.min.js:16)
    at lc (angular.min.js:16)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:163)
    at l (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: @cupcake Your error may be due to the fact you added an obsolete jQuery to the mix. It works with jQuery v3.2.1.